# OAuth2 profile fields

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm implementing OAuth2 authentication in my project. I've done it with Google and GitHub.
During the OAuth2 flow my server receives the user's profile from the identification provider.
Is there any specification of the fields of this profile?

Google and GitHub profile are different. Are there any default fields in OAuth2 profile?